# Get the user's gps location in distriqt native maps ane on android

Tags: air-native-extension

I'm using the distriqt native maps ane (Adobe Air for mobile native extension)

Is it possible to get the user location (Latitude & Longitude) on android?
On iOS i'm using NativeMapEvent.USER_LOCATION_UPDATE to get it but this is not possible on android & can't use Adobe's GeolocationEvent.UPDATE since it's buggy & doesn't work all the times, sometimes you need to restart the device to make it work :s

Comment: What are you finding buggy about the GeolocationEvent.UPDATE?

Comment: It doesn't work as it should be & sometimes without being muted the UPDATE event doesn't trigger, on some android device like the htc it doesn't trigger at all @Michael

Comment: Hi, We are adding an ANE to get user location, it will be out soon. We'll announce it via twitter (@distriqt)